# Android USB defaults to "power only"

Tags: android, usb, file-transfer

Here's a quick tip if you need to connect an Android phone (or tablet) to a PC using USB to transfer files but find that Windows "sees" the Android device but can't see the storage on the device.

The Android device may have simply decided it will just draw power from the USB connection and not allow file transfer. There is no obvious fix for this in Android setup but here's one way to diagnose the problem and then fix it.

First plug your USB cable from phone (or tablet) to PC. On your Android, tap on Settings (the sprocket icon) and find the "Wireless & networks" heading at the top, select More (with three dots to the left), then select "Tethering and portable hotspot" followed by "USB tethering". Select it and you should see the three-branch USB symbol in the status line at the top of your screen. Swipe down from the top and you should see "Tethering or hotspot active" with "Touch to set up" below it.
Just below that you may see "USB for charging" with "Touch for more options" below it. If you see this you have diagnosed the problem. Your phone is telling your PC "all I need is power" and, by implication, "don't look at my storage".

To fix the problem, tap that USB message and you should see three or four radio buttons - "Charging" (with button selected) and "File transfers" below plus one or two more options below that. Select File transfers and your PC should now see the storage on your phone - internal and (if you have it) any SD card you have installed. Transfer your files using whichever style your prefer (click and drag, copy and paste, etc)

This works for Windows 10 and Android 6.0.1 on a Wileyfox Swift (cyanogen version of Android) and Android 6.0 on a Motorola Moto G (3rd generation)

There may be a more "kosher" way round this problem but I can't find one and the Wileyfox helpline was responsive but unable to help in the end

Does anyone have a more "kosher" fix for this problem/ Especilly one that will "stick" so I don't have to do this every time I want to trnsfer stuff to/from PC to Android

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can have two problem: the first is that your phone doesn't have a SD-CARD as external memory storage. The second is that your OS doesn't have specifical driver for these devices. Can you run ADB shell on your computer?

Comment: The phone has both internal storage and a SD card. Once the USB connection has been persuaded out of "power only" mode both of these are visible to the Windows 10 PC.

Comment: I presume you mean "Android Debug Bridge". This is part of the Android SDK and I don't have time to get into Android software. I just wondered if anyone had a better fix for the USB power only problem than my rather clumsy work-around?

Comment: When you connect a phone on computer, did you get a error like "Driver not correctly installed" or "the device is not properly detected"?

Comment: Sadly no error like "Driver not correctly installed" or "the device is not properly detected"? Just no files or folders visible to Windows 10

Comment: i think you should install adb to do what you want. Otherwise, i can't help you. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

if you go into developers options go down to networking then select usb configuration and chose PTP picture transfer protocol or whichever you want this will hopefully sort the missing folder/empty issue